# SwiftUI Section view NavigationBar is white using .clipped()?

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a SwiftUI settings view where the user can manage account settings in the app.

The problem is my NavigationBar is white with the current modifiers.

If I don't use the .clipped() modifier then the NavigationBar matches the Section gray background color BUT when scrolling the Settings view up it is shown above the NavigationBar as seen in the first image.

[image]

**.clipped() is used to prevent the behavior above BUT then it makes the whole NavigationBar white so it doesn't match the default gray color that it should be.

Also, My grouped section items are not showing the default Divider lines that should be there.

2 Questions

1. How can I make my Navigation Bar match the gray Section background color.
2. How can i get the grouped together items in the same section to have Divider lines between them??

[image]

```
struct Settings: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Section(header:
                            Text("SUBSCRIPTIONS")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)) {
                        SettingsItem(
                            title: "subscriptionDetails().title",
                            content: "subscriptionDetails().level",
                            contentColor: .blue,
                            action: { print("Action") })
                    }
                Section(header:
                            Text("ACCOUNT SETTINGS")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)) {
                        SettingsItem(title: "Email", action: { print("Action")})
                        SettingsItem(title: "Gender", action: { print("Action") })
                        SettingsItem(title: "Phone Number", action:  { print("Action") })
                      })
                    }
                
                Section(header:
                            Text("PREFERENCES")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)) {
                        SettingsItem(title: "Notifications", action: { print("Action") })
                    }
                
                Section(header:
                            Text("SECURITY")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)) {
                        SettingsItem(title: "Password", action: { print("Action") })
                    }
                
                Section(header:  Text("ABOUT")
                    .foregroundColor(.black)) {
                        SettingsItem(title: "FAQ", action: { print("Action") })
                        SettingsItem(title: "About", action: { print("Action") })
                        SettingsItem(title: "Contact", action: { print("Action") })
                    }
                Section(header:
                    HStack {
                        Spacer()
                        Text("Version 1.0.0")
                        Spacer()
                    }.foregroundColor(.black)) {
                      EmptyView()
                    }
            }
            .clipped()
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
            .listStyle(.grouped)
            .navigationBarTitle("Settings", displayMode: .inline)
            .navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
            .toolbar(content: {
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarLeading) {
                    DoneButton(action: { print("Done") })
                }
                ToolbarItem(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button(action: {
                       print("Logout")
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Log Out")
                            .font(.callout).bold()
                            .foregroundColor(.red)
                    })
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

```
struct SettingsItem: View {
    var title: String
    
    var content: String?
    var contentColor: Color?
    
    let action: () -> Void
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(title)
                .font(.system(size: 18, weight: .regular))
                .foregroundColor(.black)
            Spacer()
            if let content = content, let contentColor = contentColor {
                Text(content).padding(.trailing, 10)
                    .foregroundColor(contentColor)
            }
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .bold))
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
        }.onTapGesture { print("Action") }
    }
}
```